# python : removing double quotes from string type variable

Tags: python, string, pandas

i have a list of string

```
 q = ["(df['city'] == 'Mumbai') & (df['pin'] == 12345)","(df['city'] == 'Delhi') & (df['pin'] == 12346)"]   #len(q) = 2
```

Now i have to query these two condition on my pandas dataframe

```
 d = df.query(q[0])   
 Error: df unknown
```

After checking i get to know it is for that string type

```
 d = df.query(q[0])
```

works like

```
d = df.query("(df['city'] == 'Mumbai') & (df['pin'] == 12345)")  ###string with " "
###which will not work as per syntax
####if it will be like below it should have worked
d = df.query((df['city'] == 'Mumbai') & (df['pin'] == 12345))   ###without " "
```

I have tried replace('"',''),eval(str)  but no success.

Now i believe as it is a string dtype so "" is inbuilt and will definitely come when you send a string variable across anywhere.

Is there anyway i can pass that string into df.query() without quotes(i have no idea whether it can be done by changing some dtype of that string variable or can't be done).

Please suggest.

Comment: The double quotes are not part of your string, so you can't remove them.

Comment: @timgeb-yes,you are correct..So i need to format my df.query()  part in a different way..

Comment: In theory you could put eval() around the string, but that is quite dangerous if your string comes from an untrusted source.

Comment: I'm not sure you use the pandas query syntax correctly. Can you try this: `df.query("city=='Mumbai' & pin==12345")` ?

Comment: By the way, where does your list of strings come from? You should get your query in another form which you can further process, like q = [{'city':'Mumbay','pin':12345},{'city':'....]

Comment: as i spent almost 2 hr (as i am new to python) formatting the strings inside the list and then come to a stage where it gave me no advantage...so i was just wondering if python has got any way to do that un-logical stuff....But i will take  it as a learning experience...Thank everyone..  finally only way left is @Joël's and i will try elzell's also

Comment: @elzell 's solution is definitly better, no need to build a string. Mine works though (but you need double-`=`, sorry I corrected this)

Comment: What was the issue you faced with eval?

Comment: @SiddharthGupta- when i did s = eval(q[0]) it gaves an error........KeyError: 'city'